# imBack payload to resume waterfall

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a button on my chatbot which once being clicked,
it should resume the dialog to the next step of the waterfall dialog.

I cannot find a payload value that will do that, I tried `action?resume` and `action?next`.

```
[
    (session, args, next) => {
        let msg = new builder.Message().text('welcome')
            .attachments([new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .buttons([builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'next', 'next')])])
        session.send(msg);
    }, (session, args, next) => { 
        //I'm here if button clicked - if not, handle somewhere else 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use a hero card to prompt something, i.e. wait for the user to click some button on hero card. Here is the code sample

```
bot.dialog("/", function(session) {
  session.beginDialog("test");
});

bot.dialog("test", [
  function(session) {
    // create a hero card
    let msg = new builder.Message()
      .text("welcome")
      .attachments([
        new builder.HeroCard(session).buttons([
          builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "next", "next")
        ])
      ]);
    // prompt user using hero card
    builder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
  },
  function(session, result) {
    // if user clicked some button, then do someting useful
    if (result.response === "next") {
      // do something, like calling another dialog
    } else { // user didn't clicked button, so prompt the hero card again
      session.send("please click a button");
      session.replaceDialog("test");
    }
  }
]);
```